# Copy Some Rows On New Columns - Excel

Tags: excel

I have an Excel file that contains more than 5000 rows(of data) under one column(column A). I would like to copy every 200 rows to new columns(data 1 to 200 goes to column B, data 201 to 400 goes to column C, and so on). Is there any formula to do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In B1 put:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,ROW(1:1)+(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*200)
```

Copy over 25 columns and down 200 rows.

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for your input. I'm still using the old M. Office 2007 and I think you are using a newer version. I'm not sure if it impact on the result because I'm not getting the same result. It only copied A1 to B1. Please help.

Comment: You need to copy the formula down and over. It will work for older versions.

Comment: Thanks Scott. That works on column B but then I used the same formula on the next column(column C) and it copied from rows 1 to 200 again. Do I need to change anything with the formula?

Comment: No just drag it over do not copy the formula but the cell. It will change as needed.

Comment: @MadLove see here https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/05/30/howto-use-autofill-excel/  It shows how to drag fill cells.  you out the formula in B1 and drag fill down then drag fill across.  Excel will make the changes to the formula needed so it will fill everything.  It should one be the three steps.  1. paste formula in B1. 2. Drag fill down.  3. Drag fill across.

Comment: THANK YOU very much Scott! That works like a charm. I really appreciate your help. :)

Comment: @MadLove please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.